# How to switch the window from one Browser (playing Netflix video) to another Browser using Python and Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I want to switch one window to another window using ALT+TAB Key
Can you please tell any suggestion

I used the below code, but not working

```
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com")    
driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(20)

keyAction = ActionChains(driver)
keyAction.key_down(Keys.ALT).key_down(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.ALT).key_up(Keys.TAB).perform()

time.sleep(10)

keyAction1 = ActionChains(driver)
keyAction1.key_down(Keys.ALT).key_down(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.ALT).key_up(Keys.TAB).perform()
```

Comment: Alt+Tab switching is an operating system function. Selenium works **only** in the browser. To the browser Alt+Tab means nothing! You probably want `driver.switchTo().window(...)`.

Comment: i want to switch from browser to normal window. Normal window to my browser using ALT+TAB

Comment: Selenium works **only** in the browser. You will have to use something else: AutoIT, Sikuli, Robot, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code works fine for me

I used the below code to switch the windows browser to normal browser and vice versa

```
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) #Alt
user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0) #Tab
user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 2, 0) #~Tab
user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 2, 0) #~Alt

time.sleep(10)

user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) #Alt
user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0) #Tab
user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 2, 0) #~Tab
user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 2, 0) #~Alt
```